# opening start page in mamp

Tags: mamp

Im having trouble getting into phpmyadmin in mamp, to do this i believe you have to go through the startpage,  ive tried to go into the mamp program and click 'open start page' but that takes me to the htdocs folder, ive also tried going to - localhost:8888/MAMP - and - localhost:8888/MAMP/?language=English

But both of these take me to the "Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server..." error page, any ideas how i can get to the normal start page of mamp ?

Ive been fiddleing arround a bit more with it and noticed if i go into preferences > ports > and reset MAMP ports, then go to localhost:8889 - get a string of jiberish followed by `„#08S01Got packets out of order`

Answer (score 1):

Wow strange it worked out of box for me :).
You sure did install everything and you've started all the services with MAMP Control Panel? Make sure it doesn't kill services when you close the Panel Application in options.

Comment: ive got it set to 'stop servers when quitting mamp' does that count as killing services ?

Comment: I think it does, but did you close the controller? Try reinstalling as well :P

Answer (score 0):

Need to go to Preferences... and Set to Default Apache and MySQL ports. That was my solution anyway. Hopefully someone finds this useful